# Javascript - setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript right now. I have a small issue that I can't figure out how to solve it. I would like to clear content of my html page after my function displayed "Hi hi" in web page.

```
<html>
<body onload="alertFunc()">

<script>

function alertFunc() {
  var statement = "Hi hi"
  for (let i = 0; i < statement.length; i++) {
  let c = statement.charAt(i);

  setTimeout(function(){
   document.write(c);
},i * 1000);

}

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to show hi hi first and then clear hi hi and leave the body empty ?

Comment: Yes, exactly @samairali

Comment: You should probably refrain from using document.write(). You're essentially modifying your page as a string, rather than using the DOM api. So, to target your value exclusively will become harder given any added elements. In the example you gave for instance, if you were to try and overwrite the content "hi hi" it would be difficult without also clearing out your script from the body.

Comment: thank you, I will try to solve it without using document.write().

Answer (score 1):

try this to clear content of your site after 1 second

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Learning </title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        document.write('hi hi');
        function alertFunc() {


        setTimeout(function(){
            document.write(' ');
        }, 1000);

        }
        alertFunc();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> if you want to change content with time again and again then you have to use setInterval